# Get results from all the pages using JSoup

Tags: java, jsoup

I'm using the **jsoup** library and today I got a problem.
I have to scrape **DuckDuckGo** and get all the titles of the results of a query for every page, but using

```
Document doc = Jsoup.connect("https://duckduckgo.com/html/?q=" + query).get();
```

I get only the results about the first page. How can I continue to the next pages?

Comment: Can you provide your java solution also please?

Comment: I did a bit of webscrapping, you have 2 options:
1) see how the site builds their urls, so you can mimick the next page of results, 2) try to search for the link "next page", get the link and access with jsoup to get the next batch of results, repeat after the "next page" link is disabled or not there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to extract the form parameters out of each page to get the request parameters for the next page.  This is how:

```
   public static Map<String, String> getFormParams(final Document doc) {
        return doc.select("div.nav-link > form")
                .first()
                .select("input")
                .stream()
                .filter((input) -> {
                    return input.attr("name") != null && !input.attr("name").equals("");
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(input -> input.attr("name"), input -> input.attr("value")));
    }

    public static void main(final String... args) throws IOException {
        final String baseURL = "https://duckduckgo.com/html";
        final Connection conn = Jsoup.connect(baseURL)
                .userAgent("Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.0.4; Galaxy Nexus Build/IMM76B) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.133 Mobile Safari/535.19");
        conn.data("q", "search phrase"); // Change "search phrase"

        // 1st page
        final Document page1 = conn.get();

        final Map<String, String> formParams
                = getFormParams(page1);

        // 2nd page
        final Document page2 = conn.data(formParams).get();
    }
```

Comment: Ok man, this works but I really don't get why, because i never studied something like this. Im trying to go over the second page but without any result. Can you please provide me another example? Really thanks for your 
availability

Comment: If it works, please click to accept the answer.  As mentioned, you need to use Jsoup to pull out the form parameters which what get submitted when you click to the next page.